# Переезд к новому регистратору, стерлись настройки

Tags: dns

Добрый день
Переезжали от одного регистратору к другому (только доменные имена)
 
При передаче все настройки обнулились и наши сайты и сервисы перестали работать.
Подскажите, это обычная практика (т.е. любой переезд вырубает сайты на период до 2х суток) или все таки ошибка со стороны передающего регистратора (именно он обнулил настройки и не передал их целевому регистратору)? Возможна ли "гладкая" смена регистратора?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно регистраторы позволяют указать свои DNS сервера. Если не хочется проблем при переезде (или при даунтайме у регистратора), то стоит заранее разделить DNS и саму регистрацию домена:

1. Взять сторонний сервис DNS - [Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/), например - он копеечен.
2. Перенести на него все записи.
3. Поменять неймсервера в настройках домена с регистраторских на сервера амазона для домена. Подождать пока изменения вступят в силу.
4. При переезде у нового регистратора указать те же самые сервера амазона.

Тогда смена регистратора пройдет без даунтайма.

Если новый регистратор при переезде не позволяет указать сторонние DNS сервера - то к нему не стоит переезжать вообще.

Answer (score 1):

Замена ДНС занимает время. Обычно это делается несколько часов. Но можно и "безболезненно" переезжать. Для этого нужно:
Подключите сайт в панели управления.
В настройках HTTPD отображается IP-адрес, который используется для этого сайта.
Создайте на вашем действующем DNS сервере временную A-запись для вашего домена, например

```
new.site.ru.   IN   A   123.45.67.89
```

(где "site.ru." — имя вашего сайта, а "123.45.67.89" — ваш IP-адрес)
В настройах HTTPD в поле ServerAlias добавьте имя new.site.ru
Закачайте все необходимые файлы по FTP.
При необходимости, создайте базу данных и перенесите данные.
Убедитесь, что новый сайт открывается по адресу new.site.ru и полностью функционирует.
Если у вашего сайта динамическое содержимое, которое постоянно изменяется
необходимо приостановить работу сайта, для переноса последних актуальных данных.
Сделать это можно, например, с помощью .htaccess:

```
<Files *>
  Order deny,allow
  deny from all
</Files>
```

Затем перенесите все текущие данные, включая файлы и БД, на хостинг
Поставьте переадресацию со старого хостинга с помощью .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://new.site.ru/$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

Измените DNS-серверы для вашего домена на новые.

Comment: сам сайт физически не перезжал, хостер остался тем же.Изменился только регистратор домена. Предполагалось, что новый регистратор в час X возьмет к себе права на ДНС запись и все настройки.

Comment: Замена ДНС не происходит моментально. С этим ничего нельзя поделать. 2 суток это много. Обычно всё меняется в течении 2 часов. Если бы вы переезжали на другой хостинг, то можно было бы проделать трюк описанный мной выше. Отображать сайт на старом днс, пока тот не сменится и сразу же подхватит новый хостинг. А так, только ждать.

Comment: соответствие имени и адреса остались теми же, просто "хранителем" основной записи стал другой регистратор. проблема в том, что при переезде сначала очистились все настройки (привязка хоста к IP), все это разошлось клиентам (сайт стал недоступпным), потом пока заново набрали настройки у нового регистратора, пока они разошлись по сети....
Конечно, бОльшая часть клиентов увидела изменения за те самые два часа, но отдельные проблемы с неразрешением имени сохранялись около полутора суток

Answer (score 0):

Для большей «гладкости» при подобных переездах я бы порекомендовал не пользоваться предоставляемой регистратором услугой dns-хостинга, а:

- либо держать собственные dns-серверы (как минимум два, либо разнесённых географически, либо подключенных через разных интернет-провайдеров);
- либо пользоваться услугами dns-хостинга у стороннего dns-провайдера (лучше, если их будет больше одного);
- либо комбинировать: свой dns-сервер и сторонний dns-провайдер.